# OpenNLP SentenceDetector doesn't recognize whole sentence

Tags: nlp, detection, opennlp, sentence

I'm working on a research project and I need a NLP program to detect sentences in many different circumstances. I was advised to use OpenNLP and I am convinced to use it after reading it's wiki pages. So, I use OpenNLP in order to detect sentences as well as any words or phrases which are not belong to a sentence (also called sentence fragments).

OpenNLP accepts .txt files as input if you want to redirect the input. If you want to use .doc file as input, you have to convert it to a .txt file. My problem starts right here.

I have many different files in different formats. I would like to detect sentences in each file if they consist any text. Therefore, I started to convert each potentially text containing file to a .txt file. The conversion process is not perfect. For example, if a sentence too long (say longer than a line), then conversion tool gets the both lines of the sentence as separated sentences. This results OpenNLP produces each line as different sentences because of eoln character at the end of the first line.

My question is, is there anyway that I can parameterize or configure OpenNLP to recognize whole sentence (first and second line together)?

Comment: Why don't you remove remove the redundant new lines?

Comment: Well, it's not going to help because there are some scenarios that removing redundant newline char will cause problems. For example if there  is a sentence fragment with 2 words where the first one starts with a cap letter at line x and line x+1 has another sentence fragments ends with a period. If I remove the newlines after the doc to txt conversion, OpneNLP will recognize these two lines together and will report as whole sentence. 
I think what need is to keep word wrapping during the conversion, but I don't have any clue how I could do it.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Are you using tika for text extraction? I've used it and didn't produce the problem you describe. Also, take a look at the SentenceDetectorFactory class in openNLP, it allows you to specify char[] of separators, in which perhaps you could remove the new lines as a valid separator. This implies you are training the model though .

Comment: @Daniel Here is an example of the problem. Let's say we have a doc file contains the following sentence:"The Apache OpenNLP library is a machine learning based toolkit for the processing of natural language text. It supports the most common NLP tasks, such as tokenization, sentence segmentation, part-of-speech tagging, named entity extraction, chunking, parsing, and coreference resolution." When I use "catdoc" to convert txt file and give it to OpenNLP as an input file, I receive the following lines as sentences:

Comment: @Daniel(1)The Apache OpenNLP library is a machine learning based toolkit for the processing of natural language text. (2)It supports the most (3)common NLP tasks, such as tokenization, sentence segmentation, part-of-speech tagging, named entity extraction, chunking, (4)parsing, and coreference resolution. (5)These tasks are usually required to build more advanced text processing services.

Comment: @markg I use catdoc, but I'll try tika. As for the delimiter used in SentenceDetector, I don't think it's trivial to figure out when to remove which newline character. It seems it's as difficult as sentence boundary problem.

Comment: @Lorderon Check if I am understanding your correctly. So at (3) and (4) you have new lines which makes your system think that they are separate sentences; right? And what happens if you remove all new lines? (please show in the above example)

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, that's exactly what happens. My problem will be resolved when I remove the newlines for the example above. However, it'll cause other problems. I have the previous example in order to show to deal with wrapping issue. As proposed, if I remove the newlines, then some of the sentence fragments will be combined although they are not belong to a sentence. Hope, this is clear!

Comment: @Lorderon No it is not clear to me. I think you need to replace new line with a space. This should solve your problem. If not, give me an example.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry for the confusion. It doesn't work and here is the example. Say the original content is: `This sentence is supposed to be a long sentence which will have some words located in multiple lines.\n Now, the second sentence starts and it's not as long as the first one.\n This one\n is not intended\n to be a sentence.` Now the OpenNLP result will be as follows: `This sentence is supposed to be a long sentence which will\n have some words located in multiple lines.\n Now, the second sentence starts and it's not as long as the first one.\n This one\n is not intended\n to be a sentence.`

Comment: @Daniel So, if I replace the newlines with spaces then I will get the following: `(1)This sentence is supposed to be a long sentence which will have some words located in multiple lines.(2) Now, the second sentence starts and it's not as long as the first one.(3) This one is not intended to be a sentence.` As you see, it will give me last 3 lines from the original text as a whole sentence because it looks like a sentence. However, last 3 lines are supposed to be reported as individual sentences. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: What are the numbers (1), (2), (3)? You just added here or you had them before giving the paragraph to OpenNLp?

Comment: @Daniel They are the line numbers, not part of the line. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you, use apache Tika for that conversion of different files.
Apache Tika has AutoDetectParser which detects different file types and extracts the data in it (Even metadata if you want) and you can save that into a .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Try your paragraph with new lines replaced with spaces with CoreNLP: nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/process